# Multiple words concordance in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a words file to find their concordances in a text (maximum 3 positions right and left)

Words file:

> buy
>
> time
>
> glass
>
> home
>
> red

Text file:

> After almost a decade selling groceries online, Amazon has failed to make a major dent on its own as consumers have shown a stubborn urge to buy items like fruits, vegetables and meat in person.
>   Do you find yourself spending more time on your phone than you ... mindlessly passing time on a regular basis by staring at your phone?
>   The process can be fraught with anxiety, as many different glass styles are available, and points of view clash on what is proper and necessary

Script:

```
def keywordsContext(file, fileName):
    #file: text file
    #fileName: words file

    with open(file, "r") as f, open(fileName, "r") as fi:

        corpus = f.read().split()
        pivot = fi.read().split()

        for keywords in pivot:
            if keywords in corpus:
                index = pivot.index(keywords)
                contexts = keywords+":", pivot[index-3:index], pivot[index+1:index+4]
                print(contexts)
            else:
                pass
```

Output:

> ('buy:', [], ['time', 'glass', 'home'])
>
> ('time:', [], ['glass', 'home', 'red'])
>
> ('glass:', [], ['home', 'red'])
>
> None

Output I wanted:

> 'buy': stubborn urge to buy items like fruits
>
> 'time': yourself spending more time on your phone
>
> 'glass': as many different glass styles are available

**EDIT**

And... if the same word appears more than once? I did a test (with one more sentence in the corpus to repeat the word 'glass'). I tried putting a while len (corpus) != 0 but it's a loop that repeats with the same outputs...

```
def keywordsContext(file, fileName):

    with open(file, "r") as f, open(fileName, "r") as fi:

        corpus = f.read().split()
        pivot = fi.read().split()

        while len(corpus) != 0:

            for keywords in pivot:
                if keywords in corpus:
                    inde = corpus.index(keywords)
                    contexts = keywords+": "+ ' '.join(corpus[inde-3:inde+4])
                    print(contexts)
```

**Output:**

> buy: stubborn urge to buy items like fruits,
>
> time: yourself spending more time on your phone
>
> glass: as many different glass styles are available,
>
> buy: stubborn urge to buy items like fruits,
>
> time: yourself spending more time on your phone
>
> glass: as many different glass styles are available,
>
> buy: stubborn urge to buy items like fruits,
>
> time: yourself spending more time on your phone
>
> glass: as many different glass styles are available,
>
> ...

Comment: I edited my post, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mistakes with lists names. Try it:

```
def keywordsContext(file, fileName):
#file: text file
#fileName: words file

with open(file, "r") as f, open(fileName, "r") as fi:

    corpus = f.read().split()
    pivot = fi.read().split()
    for keywords in pivot:
        if keywords in corpus:
            lst_index = 0
            for i in range(0, corpus.count(keywords)):
                inde = corpus.index(keywords, lst_index)
                contexts = keywords+": "+ ' '.join(corpus[inde-3:inde+4])
                lst_index = inde+1
                print(contexts)
        else:
            pass
```

EDITED: According to OP edit, this program print all occurences of word

Answer (score 3):

```
def keywordsContext(file, fileName):
    #file: text file
    #fileName: words file
    with open(file, "r") as f, open(fileName, "r") as fi:

        corpus = f.read().split()
        pivot = fi.read().split()
        for keywords in pivot:
            if keywords in corpus:
                index = corpus.index(keywords)
                contexts = "'" + keywords + "' : " + " ".join(corpus[index - 3 : index + 4])
                print(contexts)
            else:
                pass
```

Output:

```
'buy' : stubborn urge to buy items like fruits,
'time' : yourself spending more time on your phone
'glass' : as many different glass styles are available,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def keywordsContext(file, fileName):

    with open(file, "r") as f, open(fileName, "r") as fi:

        corpus = f.read().split()
        pivot = fi.read().split()
        for keywords in pivot:
            if keywords in corpus:
                index = corpus.index(keywords)
                contexts = keywords+":", corpus[index-3:index+4]
                print(contexts)
            else:
                pass
```

Output

```
('buy:', ['stubborn', 'urge', 'to', 'buy', 'items', 'like', 'fruits,'])
('time:', ['yourself', 'spending', 'more', 'time', 'on', 'your', 'phone'])
('glass:', ['as', 'many', 'different', 'glass', 'styles', 'are', 'available,'])
```